# UIStackView programmatically filled with UIViews doesn't scroll inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm still a SO and Swift newbie, so please, be patient   :-)

I have a `UIViewController`.

Inside this `viewcontroller` there's a `UIScrollView`.

Inside the `UIScrollView` there's a `UIStackView` (pinned with `AutoLayout` at 0,0,0,0 and centered vertically and horizontally), with horizontal axis.

My goal is to add subviews to the stackview and make the scrollview scroll horizontally.

So, I did the following:

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var scroller: UIScrollView!
        @IBOutlet weak var stack: UIStackView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()
            scroller.delegate = self

            for i in 0..<10 {

                let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 128))
                // .random is unimportant here
                customView.backgroundColor = .random()
                stack.addArrangedSubview(customView)

            }

        }

        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
            self.scroller.contentSize = CGSize(width:2400,height:128)
            print(self.scroller.contentSize) // 2400
            print(self.stack.subviews)
        }

        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            print("scrollin'")
        }


    }
```

Problem is there is something I must be missing because the scrollview doesn't scroll at all. I only see one view (of course, anytime with a different color).

I'm sure the views are loaded because this is second print output:

```
[<UIView: 0x159e01a10; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115d7a0>>, <UIView: 0x159e03f10; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115d800>>, <UIView: 0x159e046d0; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115d960>>, <UIView: 0x159e0e410; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115da80>>, <UIView: 0x159e0e7c0; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115db20>>, <UIView: 0x159e0e9a0; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115da60>>, <UIView: 0x159e0eb80; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115dbe0>>, <UIView: 0x159e0ed60; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115dc80>>, <UIView: 0x159e0ef40; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115dd20>>, <UIView: 0x159e0f120; frame = (0 0; 240 128); layer = <CALayer: 0x28115ddc0>>]
```

So, what is it happening? Why the scrollview doesn't scroll?

Comment: @matt: can I ask you why you removed your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Replace this

```
  let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 128))
```

with

```
let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat( i * 240 ) , y: 0, width: 240, height: 128))
```

I see no need for the stackView , and

```
scroller.addSubview(customView)
```

Look to this [Scroller](https://github.com/ShKhan9/Scroller)

[image]

Comment: This has been my first attempt and it didn't work (I confirm it doesn't work)

Comment: don't miss `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()` also what constraints you give to the scrollview in IB ?

Comment: You're right about viewDidLayoutSubviews. Constraints of the scrollview in IB: centered vertically and horizontally, width=240, height=128 (same as a single subview)

Comment: @Planemo check the demo

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted! I upvote (when I can, at the moment it looks like I can't) because I don't like downvotes for people genuinely trying to help other people

Answer (score -1):

try this code, i hope it helps you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    scroller.delegate = self

        for i in 0..<10 {
            let xPosition = 240 * CGFloat(i)
            let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: 240, height: 128))
            // .random is unimportant here
            customView.backgroundColor = .random()
            scroller.addSubview(customView)
        }
    scroller.contentSize.width = 2400
}
```

Comment: I set contentSize in viewDidLayoutSubviews: isn't it ok?

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted! I came here and found two downvotes and an answer removed. When I can, I upvote your answer